# Azure AD + Graph API + Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-graph, azure-ad

I am not able to get the list of all sites from sharepoint by using app id and key from azure app registration and using the graph api
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

It just returns the root site children.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its because your sites are not crawled yet? For me it just works fine. When I create a fresh site collection it takes upto 8 hours to reflect in search result.